# Overloading << operator in a doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the `<< operator` to be an *"`insert_first` operator"*  for a double linked list. This should be a simple procedure, and I have overloaded operators before, but I am stuck on this one. I am trying to overload it as:

```
DLList & DLList::operator << (const int value ) 
{
    insert_first(value);
}
```

My `.h` file seems fine, and is similar to other ones online:

```
#ifndef DLLIST_H
#define DLLISH_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class ListNode {
public:
    int value; 

    ListNode * next;
    ListNode * prev;

    static int node_count;

    ListNode() {
        node_count++;
    }

    ~ListNode() {
        node_count--;
    }

    static void print_node_count() {
        std::cout << "Node Count: " << node_count << std::endl;
    }
};

class DLList {
private:
    ListNode * head;
public:
    DLList();
    ~DLList();

    void print_list();
    void print_list( std::string list_name );
    void insert_first( int value );

    bool remove( int value );
    void concat_list( DLList * list_to_add );

    DLList & operator << (const int value );
};
```

and my `insert_first` function also seems to be working fine:

```
void DLList::insert_first( int value ) 
{
    ListNode * n = new ListNode();

    n->value = value;
    n->next = head->next;
    n->prev = head;

    head->next = n;
    n->next->prev = n;    
}
```

The error I'm receiving is a segfault. Any ideas or comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not returning anything from `operator <<` when you told the compiler it would return a `DLList&`.

Comment: You don't return `*this` meaning `operator<<` has undefined behavior (no return type in a non-void function)

Comment: I see it now, thank you

Comment: why does "insert_first" actually insert it after `head` ?

Comment: that's just the way it's written. head doesn't store a value, it's just there for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so as the comments suggested, I needed to return something from the operator like

```
DLList & DLList::operator << (const int value ) 
{
insert_first(value);
return *this; 
}
```